# Website Images - Loss of quality

Tags: php, wordpress, image

The images on my web page seem to "lose" quality / color in thumbnail sizing.
[Link To Site](https://leemoophotography.co.za/project/taryn/)

I have tried to insert the following to prevent Wordpress from compression the images - I then regenerated thumbnails, howver problem still exists.
The images display correctly upon opening - the error is with the thumbnails

```
add_filter('jpeg_quality', function($arg){return 100;});
```

I have also tried setting the plugin "[imsanity](https://wordpress.org/plugins/imsanity/)" quality to 100 - and also tried deactiving the plugin and reuploading new files.  So I am doubtful this is the problem.

I am using DIVI theme.  have tried DIVI support who believe the problem is not with the theme.

any advice please?  Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to search the web for 'wordpress thumbnail quality'? You should get a couple of hits, most telling you that changing jpeg_quality will not have an effect since 3.52 or somesuch; this looks promising: https://wordpress.2bearstudio.com/improve-thumbnail-quality-in-wordpress/ ; it advocates using imagemagick instead of gd for thumbnail generation.

Comment: @TomRegner thank you. I have installed the WP Plugin, however am receiving this error:  Imagick PHP module not found.  I do not think I am able to uplad imagemagick due to the fact that I am on shared hosting ?

Comment: than this solution doesn't work for you; maybe you can ask your hoster to install IM, but I wouldn't bet on it :(

Comment: @TomRegner I will try that, thank you.    anything else I could try perhaps